# Is time a measurement of Entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy

Is time a measurement of entropy? Is it because time is increasing forever?

Well after reading about the Second Law of Thermodynamics and working with Entropy, I began to realize that if time can be interpreted as a measure of Entropy, since it is always increasing.

> Since almost everything decays with time, I thought that time could be
>   a measure of Entropy. Since it is achieving the lowest energy state
>   possible.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate and improve your question? Right now it looks like you thought too much about II law of thermodynamics ;)

Comment: Yep, you seem to be confused... Is it connected with the most common problem with thermodynamics, like: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24669/does-adsorption-violate-thermodynamics ?

Comment: yeah, It is kind of measure of entropy

Comment: Related fun fact: http://numb3rs.wolfram.com/511/

Answer (score 4):

Time and entropy has not much to do with each other.

From practical point of view: Equilibrium systems can hang around for infinite time, and their entropy does not change at all - so time would be an impractical measure.

From conceptual point of view: Entropy comes from statistical behavior of the system of many bodies. Time is unrelated to statistics; it exist even in single body systems.

Comment: Most systems that are said to be in perpetual equilibrium (say a pendulum which ignores any friction) would go for ever. However, in reality it does loose it’s energy as “time” goes by. Causing its entropy to increase until it remains stationary. Similarly the entropy of the whole universe is going in the same direction, and this is just a statistical phenomena (the second law).

Comment: @RSM This is not true. You mix up thermodynamic and mechanical systems in an incorrect way. A given volume of gas will not just cool down due to some friction.